# Get a server-safe timestamp in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, date, timestamp

I would like to get the current Date/Time in actionscript 3, and I want to avoid the Date class since the system time can be easily manipulated by the user.

Can I access a server and get a timestamp?

Is there a better alternative to this method (a simple URL-request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

The flash side:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
loader.load(new URLRequest("yourserverpage.php"))
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded)
function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    var date:Date;
    try{
        date = new Date(Number(loader.data));
    }catch(e:Error){
    }

    if(!date){
        //flash couldn't convert the date properly, there was an error
    }
}
```

And the php side:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print time() * 1000;
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I wanted. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 2):

Anything you can do in ActionScript can be manipulated by the user since it runs on its own computer, and you can't do anything about it.

That said, you can get the current timestamp from a server you own (for crossdomain reason). Just output a time() in PHP (for instance) and get it via an URLLoader.

Comment: The returned value could still be tampered with easily. The most secure would be checking the date on the server itself.

Comment: @WillKru Yes, totally, that was the point of my first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Im aware that the Date object could be tampered with via code. But even changing the time settings (anyone can do this), will change the Date object...

Comment: I made an example of how to do this suggestion as an answer (as I had done one last week for the same thing), @Jake, please upvote this answer (once you have enough reputation to do so) as they were the first to contribute and my answer is along the same lines as this.